# is there a way to get date difference over a certain column

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i want to calculate the time difference/date difference for each unique name it took for the status to get from order to arrived.

Input dataframe is like this

```
+------------------------------+
| Date      | id | name |staus
+------------------------------+
| 1986/10/15| A  |john |order
| 1986/10/16| A  |john |dispatched
| 1986/10/18| A  |john |arrived
| 1986/10/15| B  |peter|order
| 1986/10/16| B  |peter|dispatched
| 1986/10/17| B  |peter|arrived
| 1986/10/16| C  |raul |order
| 1986/10/17| C  |raul |dispatched
| 1986/10/18| C  |raul |arrived
+-----------------------------+
```

the expected output dataset should look similar to this

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| id | name |time_difference_from_order_to_delivered|
+---------------------------------------------------+
 A   | john |                3days
 B   |peter |                2days
 C   | Raul |                2days
+---------------------------------------------------+
I am stuck on what logic to implement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by and calculate the date diff using a conditional aggregation:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('id', 'name').agg(
    F.datediff(
        F.to_date(F.max(F.when(F.col('staus') == 'arrived', F.col('Date'))), 'yyyy/MM/dd'),
        F.to_date(F.min(F.when(F.col('staus') == 'order', F.col('Date'))), 'yyyy/MM/dd')
    ).alias('time_diff')
)

df2.show()
+---+-----+---------+
| id| name|time_diff|
+---+-----+---------+
|  A| john|        3|
|  C| raul|        2|
|  B|peter|        2|
+---+-----+---------+
```

You can also directly subtract the dates, which will return an interval type column:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('id', 'name').agg(
    (
        F.to_date(F.max(F.when(F.col('staus') == 'arrived', F.col('Date'))), 'yyyy/MM/dd') -
        F.to_date(F.min(F.when(F.col('staus') == 'order', F.col('Date'))), 'yyyy/MM/dd')
    ).alias('time_diff')
)

df2.show()
+---+-----+---------+
| id| name|time_diff|
+---+-----+---------+
|  A| john|   3 days|
|  C| raul|   2 days|
|  B|peter|   2 days|
+---+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ordered is the earliest date and delivered is the last, just use aggregation and `datediff()`:

```
select id, name, datediff(max(date), min(date)) as num_days
from t
group by id, name;
```

For more precision, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, name,
       datediff(max(case when status = 'arrived' then date end)
                min(case when status = 'order' then date end)
               ) as num_days
from t
group by id, name;
```

Comment: datediff won't work because the date format is non-standard.

Comment: @mck . . . Fix your data!  Storing dates in strings is just wrong -- whether in SQL or any other tool that supports native date formats.